# Does quantum probability entangle reliability?

Tags: quantum-states

When I search here for "probabilty reliability" I find eight questions, only a couple coming close to but not exactly on this one.  Perhaps this has been covered elsewhere but mild googling doesn't find anything obvious to me.

I have a living cat owned by Schrödinger that won't die during an experiment except by poison or explosives.  I put the cat in a box.  The box also has a radioactive atom that has a 50% probability of decaying during the experiment.  If decay happens, it releases the poison or sets off the explosives killing the cat.  The box also has a 'living cat' detector that is only 75% reliable in either decay outcome that we use one time at the end of the experiment.

My question is about the number of quantum states after detection, which is why I ask here and not on Math.stackexchange.com.  Are there just two quantum states still in effect or four?   BTW, PBS Studios Space Time seems to me to say four but I'm still holding out for two.

Comment: By my understanding, there are 3 quantum states—$|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$, and superposition. if you have a detector that is only 75% reliable, the number of states will not change, you will only have a slightly less reliable result, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I said after detection.  Doesn't that eliminate or change superposition?

Comment: Oops... Sorry, I missed that part. When you say "after detection", I presume you are using the living cat detector to determine whether or not the cat is dead or alive. Using the detector, you would only have a 75% accuracy, which means that superposition has not yet been completely eliminated, the superposition of the states has simply changed.

Comment: So I have discovered 'partial superposition'.  Which is only a partial quantum state?  Maybe there is something such as partial entanglement.  It's trickier than I can figure.

Comment: Potentially useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Mixed_states

Comment: Thanks Nihar.  Now I'm studying purification of pure state or states.  Starting to sound like four separate non-superimposed quantum states.  Good place to look further.